# WordPress download a file instead of opening in browser

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm using nginx and php-fpm7.2 on my server. When I try to open my WordPress website, it won't load and just download the page. I can access all other pages except the homepage through url. It occurs today and I didn't modify any config files. The fastcgi and the other sites on the same server is working. I've tried any solutions I can find and none of it can solve.
The file download by the website is below

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';
```

This is the config file of my website

```
server
    {
        listen 80;
        #listen [::]:80;
        server_name sur.net.cn ;
        index index.php ;
        root  /home/wwwroot/sur.net.cn;

        include rewrite/none.conf;
        #error_page   404   /404.html;
        include enable-php.conf;
        # Deny access to PHP files in specific directory
        #location ~ /(wp-content|uploads|wp-includes|images)/.*\.php$ { deny all; }

        location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
        {
            expires      30d;
        }

        location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
        {
            expires      12h;
        }

        location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
        }

        location ~ /\.
        {
            deny all;
        }

        access_log off;
    }

server
    {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        #listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name sur.net.cn ;
        index index.php ;
        root  /home/wwwroot/sur.net.cn;

        ssl_certificate /home/wwwroot/ssl/5176542_sur.net.cn.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/wwwroot/ssl/5176542_sur.net.cn.key;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "TLS13-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS13-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS13-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS13-AES-128-CCM-8-SHA256:TLS13-AES-128-CCM-SHA256:EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5";
        ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
        # openssl dhparam -out /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/dhparam.pem 2048
        ssl_dhparam /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/dhparam.pem;

        include rewrite/none.conf;
        #error_page   404   /404.html;
        include enable-php.conf;
        # Deny access to PHP files in specific directory
        #location ~ /(wp-content|uploads|wp-includes|images)/.*\.php$ { deny all; }

        location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
        {
            expires      30d;
        }

        location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
        {
            expires      12h;
        }

        location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
        }

        location ~ /\.
        {
            deny all;
        }
       

        access_log off;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
```

as written here: https://dariuscoder.com/2021/09/29/wordpress-nginx-config/
If I remove this part, I get same effect - it downloads instead of executing.

Also if it still downloads – make sure you have restarted nginx and clear browser cache. Chrome was downloading file even with stopped nginx until I cleared cache.